# Using GLPK with Pyomo

Tags: pyomo, glpk

The troubles of using GLPK with pyomo seem to be legendary.
I also tried without success to run a little pyomo script that solves a trivial assignment problem with GLPK as the the solver.

None of the tips that helped others, like setting PATH variables or installing scikit-glpk worked for me.

I am working under windows and use WinPython that I have relocated to a "non-standard" folder.

When I looked into some of the batch files that come with the GLPK download, I saw that they contain some definitions for paths that e.g. define the expected(?) location of the source files for building GLPK:

In Build_CLL.bat that looks like

```
rem Build GLPK for C#/CLI DLL with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
rem and Windows SDK 7.1.
rem NOTE: Make sure that the following variables specify correct paths:
rem HOME, SWIG, SDK, NET.

rem Path to GLPK source (glpk.h will be in $(GLPK_HOME)/src)
set GLPK_HOME=".."
rem Path to Visual Studio Express
set HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"
rem Path to SwigWin
set SWIG="C:\Program Files (x86)\swig\swigwin-3.0.12"
rem Path to Windows SDK
set SDK="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10"
rem Path to .NET Framework
set NET="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\"

set PATH=%NET%;%PATH%  
...
```

> **Question:**
>
> What are the "assumptions" of the batch files regarding the location from where they are invoked?
>
> What role does it play from where `pip install` is called?

as reportedly anaconda manages to correctly install GLPK as a pyomo solver there must be some preconditions that must be met in order to be able to use GLPK for pyomo.